# n-squared / 2 chunking for parallel processing

Tags: math, parallel-processing

I have an n-squared loop that I want to break up into chunks to run concurrently. The loop looks like this:

```
for i = n to m
    for j = i to m
       // Do something
```

**Edit based on comment:**
Concrete example with n = 0, m = 60000:

```
for i = 0 to 60000
  for j = i to 60000
```

So, I am not really doing n-squared iterations, but, n-squared / 2. As i gets greater, the number of iterations in the inner look becomes less.

Let's say n = 0 and m = 60000, and I want to break this into 5 separate processes to be run on parallel. How do I chose n and m so that the 5 different processes have equal iterations?

I know 60000 / 5 = 12000. So, we could break it up like this:

```
0 - 11999
12000 - 23999
24000 - 35999
36000 - 47999
48000 - 60000
```

The idea is to break this up into x loops (Where x is 5 here) with equal numbers of iterations. Something like this:

```
for i = 0 to 11999
    for j = i to 60000

for i = 12000 to 23999
    for j = i to 60000

for i = 24000 to 35999
    for j = i to 60000

for i = 36000 to 47999
    for j = i to 60000

for i = 48000 to 60000
    for j = i to 60000
```

But, the loops at the end will have less comparisons. So, this is not the right answer.

Seems like this is a calculus problem where you need to figure out equal areas under a curve. But, that math is about 20 years rusty for me. I am, of course, looking for a general solution given n = 0 and m > 0.

**Edit 2:**
Clarification to the problem above.

Thanks

Comment: I added a concrete example. But, I think my original problem statement is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I might write the nested loops in a language, such as Fortran or Matlab, which allows one to specify the stride of a loop.   I expect this can be translated into most other programming languages with loops.

I'll suppose that your concurrent program is spread across threads (or processes, it doesn't matter much which) and that there is a function `num_pids` which returns the number of processes in the computation and another function , `my_pid`, which returns on integer in the range `0..num_pids-1`.

Then, in pseudo-Fortran I would write

```
do i = my_pid, m, num_pids
    do j = i, m
    ....
    end do
end do
```

Interpret the triplet `my_pid, m, num_pids` to mean *`from my_pid to m in steps of num_pids`*.  This won't give exactly balanced loads but the balance should be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: Ah, so you would create a step in the outer loop based on the number of processes / threads? Gotcha. I had not thought of that.  I was stuck on trying to figure out begin / end numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinct pattern for the number of iterations in the inner loop that can be leveraged to divide the work more evenly.  The number of iterations in the inner loop decreases by one with every iteration of the outer loop.  So, the number of inner loop iterations are:

```
       inner
 i   iterations
---  ----------
 0     m
 1     m-1
 2     m-2
 .     .
 .     .
 .     .
m-2    2
m-1    1 
 m     0
```

From this tableau, it can be seen that the number of total inner iterations for `i=0` and `i=m` is `m`.  Also, the number of total inner iterations for `i=1` and `i=m-1` is `m`. In fact, for any `c` the total inner iterations for `i=c` and `i=m-c` is `m` (save the case where the number of outer iterations is odd).

With this fact, assigning processes can be done on a per outer iteration basis to better distribute the load evenly.  Simply assign the entire inner loop to the processes in a serpentining fashion.  For the case of 5 processes, the assignment follows this pattern:

```
 i   process 
---  --------
 0     1     
 1     2     
 2     3     
 3     4
 4     5
 5     5
 6     4
 7     3 
 8     2
 9     1
 .     .
 .     .
 .     .
```

With this approach, each process will work on about the same number of inner loop iterations especially for large `m` values.